# Find the area above the $x-$ axis included between the parabola $y^2=ax$ and the circle $x^2+y^2=2ax$.

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find the area above the $x-$ axis included between the parabola $y^2=ax$ and the circle $x^2+y^2=2ax$.

The circle $x^2+y^2=2ax$ can be represented as $(x-a)^2+y^2=a^2$ which has centre at $(a,0)$ and radius $a$.

Since they both intersect at $(0,0)$ and $(a,a)$ so the area included will be

$\int _0^a \int _0^{\sqrt {ax}} dy dx-\int_0^a \int _0^{\sqrt {2ax-x^2}}dy dx$

But the problem is I am unable to compute the 2nd integral.

The answer to the first is $\frac{2}{3}a^{{2}}$.

Please help to solve it.

Comment: The integral with respect to $y$ is very easy, for the rest of the calculation substitute $x=u+a$ then a trig or hyperbolic substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The graph is drawn taking $a=2$. What you need to notice is that the second integral is just $1/4$-th the area of the circle. So required area is $$\int_0^a\sqrt{ax}dx+\frac{\pi a^2}4=\frac{a^2}{3/2}+\frac{\pi a^2}4$$

Comment: the title says above the x-axis, so I think the multiplicative coeff $2$ is not required. also shouldn't there be a subtraction somewhere...

Comment: @zwim i edited the answer. Why do think there would be a subtraction

Comment: because it is the area between the two curves, so you want to substract the integral to the circle area.

Comment: No i have taken the integral from $0$ to $a$., Not from $0$ to $2a$. See the graph.

Comment: I think this should be $\frac{\pi a^2}{4} - \frac{a^2}{3/2}$. The first is the area of the quarter-circle; the second is the area inside the parabola from $x=0$ to $x=a$.